# Error installing PyPI xmlsec==1.3.3 Python2

Tags: python-2.7, pip, archlinux, xmlsec

I am using arch and installing this xmlsec package using pip 20.3.4 in virtualenv (python 2.7)
Although official pages (github and pypi) doesn't specifically include arch dependencies, still I think I have installed all of them.

I have installed:

```
extra/xmlsec 1.2.32-1 [installed]
community/python-xmlsec 1.3.11-1 [installed]
extra/libxml2 2.9.10-9 [installed]
extra/libxml++ 3.2.3-1 [installed]
multilib/lib32-libxml2 2.9.10-4 [installed]
```

My gcc version is 11.1.0

I am getting this error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pkgconfig in ./cen/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from xmlsec==1.3.3) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.0 in ./cen/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from xmlsec==1.3.3) (4.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec
Building wheel for xmlsec (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/astanwar99/DevSpace/central/cen/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-y4lh42
    cwd: /tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/
Complete output (53 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'xmlsec' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -DNDEBUG -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fPIC -DMODULE_NAME=xmlsec -DMODULE_VERSION=1.3.3 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DY.....
.
.
In file included from /tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c:10:
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c: In function ‘PyXmlSec_ConstantsModule_Init’:
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c:278:50: error: ‘xmlSecXkmsNs’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘xmlSecXPathNs’?
    278 |     tmp = PyString_FromString((const char*)(JOIN(xmlSec, name))); \
        |                                                  ^~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/common.h:21:23: note: in definition of macro ‘DO_JOIN2’
    21 | #define DO_JOIN2(X,Y) X##Y
        |                       ^
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/common.h:19:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘DO_JOIN1’
    19 | #define JOIN(X,Y) DO_JOIN1(X,Y)
        |                   ^~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c:278:45: note: in expansion of macro ‘JOIN’
    278 |     tmp = PyString_FromString((const char*)(JOIN(xmlSec, name))); \
        |                                             ^~~~
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c:288:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT’
    288 |     PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT(XkmsNs, "XKMS");
        |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c:278:50: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    278 |     tmp = PyString_FromString((const char*)(JOIN(xmlSec, name))); \
        |                                                  ^~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/common.h:21:23: note: in definition of macro ‘DO_JOIN2’
    21 | #define DO_JOIN2(X,Y) X##Y
        |                       ^
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/common.h:19:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘DO_JOIN1’
    19 | #define JOIN(X,Y) DO_JOIN1(X,Y)
        |                   ^~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c:278:45: note: in expansion of macro ‘JOIN’
    278 |     tmp = PyString_FromString((const char*)(JOIN(xmlSec, name))); \
        |                                             ^~~~
/tmp/pip-install-E6BWHU/xmlsec/src/constants.c:288:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT’
    288 |     PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT(XkmsNs, "XKMS");
        |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Running setup.py clean for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
Installing collected packages: xmlsec
    Running setup.py install for xmlsec ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You don't need to install `python-xmlsec` from Arch's repo if you're planning on `pip install`ing it in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.

1. Clone this repo https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec
2. Checkout this [commit](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/tree/b7e940872c318de4fb3a4520c67812e7585df1b9) (python 2.7 still supported)
3. Make the changes of this [commit](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/commit/ce45868701220368f156114978c784cc5200d80c) manually.
4. pip install .

For more details: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=266798

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on MacOS Monterey

```
 CPPFLAGS="-DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1" pip install xmlsec==1.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

[XMLSec's PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/) says the newest version of the library is only compatible with Python 3.

It looks like [version 1.3.9](https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/1.3.9/) still claims Python 2 compatibility, so you might want to try

```
pip install xmlsec==1.3.9
```

or, you know, better yet, make the switch to Python 3.

Comment: @AKK I want xmlsec==1.3.3 (added in the title). Its a dependency of a project so cant help that. But I know people who got it working on ubuntu. Might be specific to arch, not sure though

Comment: Well, you could _try_ 1.3.9, couldn't you? A patch version change shouldn't break things, but they could have fixed the build.

Comment: I tried 1.3.9, still getting gcc related errors (but different). I believe I am missing some kind of dependency,

Comment: Make sure you have libxml2, not just libxml++?

Comment: Yes I have that as well. Can downgrading gcc help?